# Limitation extending generics in java, any way to get around it?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have the following model to make controllers in my application. Obviously, the full model is more complex but I will focus on the only part that is causing me problems:

```
public abstract AbstractController<T> {
    abstract protected Class<T> getType();
}

public ParentController extends AbstractController<Parent> {
    @Override
    protected Class<Parent> getType() {
        return Parent.class;
    }
}
```

Now I would like to extend the Parent object and have a controller for the son, it would look like this:

```
public SonController extends ParentController {
    @Override
    protected Class<Son> getType() {
        return Son.class;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the method getType() shows incompatibility in compilation (expects the class Parent).

I tried to play around with the generics but I can't find a solution. The method getType is used in several methods from the abstract controller and I would really like to avoid overriding those.

Any ideas would be wellcome.

Comment: A solution would be to have: public class ParentController<P> extends AbstractController<P extends Parent>. Then SonController extends ParentController<Son>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could change the `getType` return `Class<? extends T>`.

```
abstract protected Class<? extends T> getType();
```

Then `ParentController` and `SonController` would look like

```
public class ParentController extends AbstractController<Parent> {
    @Override
    protected Class<? extends Parent> getType() {
        return Parent.class;
    }
}

public class SonController extends ParentController {
    @Override
    protected Class<? extends Parent> getType() {
        return Son.class;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Generics are invariant to begin with, so `Class<Son>` can not be assigned to `Class<Parent>` (in your case these are not covariant return types).

But *wildcard with an extends-bound (upper bound) makes the type covariant*, thus this would solve it:

```
public abstract class AbstractController<T> {
    abstract protected Class<? extends T> getType();
}

public class ParentController extends AbstractController<Parent> {
    @Override
    protected Class<? extends Parent> getType() {
        return Parent.class;
    }
}

class SonController extends ParentController {
    @Override
    protected Class<? extends Parent> getType() {
        return Son.class;
    }
}
```